# Accessing nested property in json-ld frame

Tags: json, json-ld

So, this is my json-ld data:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/id2",
    "http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm": [
      {
        "@value": "Secondary entity"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/id1",
    "http://example.com/describedBy": [
      {
        "@id": "http://example.com/id2"
      }
    ],
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label": [
      {
        "@value": "Main entity"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is the frame I'm using:

```
{
  "@context" :
    {
      "label": {
        "@id":"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      },
      "describedBy": {
        "@id":"http://example.com/describedBy"
      },
      "id": "@id",
      "@vocab" : "http://example.com/",
      "@base" : "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph" : {
    "describedBy": {}
  }
}
```

The result I'm getting looks like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "label": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
    },
    "describedBy": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/describedBy"
    },
    "id": "@id",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/",
    "@base": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "id": "id1",
  "describedBy": {
    "id": "id2",
    "http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm": "Secondary entity"
  },
  "label": "Main entity"
}
```

Is it possible to frame that data to look like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "label": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
    },
    "describedBy": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/describedBy"
    },
    "id": "@id",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/",
    "@base": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "id": "id1",
  "describedById": "id2",
  "describedByLabel": "Secondary entity",
  "label": "Main entity"
}
```

Which is basically creating two new properties: `describedById` and `describedByLabel` based on previous `describedBy` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't really do this with framing, as "Secondary entity" is a property of the node for "id2", and this would require promoting it to be a property of the "id1" node.

You could do this with a SPARQL CONSTRUCT, but JSON-LD doesn't allow you to really create new data.